# How to typeset Hermann–Mauguin notations for space groups?

Tags: spacing, formatting

There is a related question: [Typesetting Hermann-Mauguin notation correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276528/typesetting-hermann-mauguin-notation-correctly).
It gives nice spacings and symbols.

But it only deals with point groups, not space groups, which require more complicated symbols. Like this: [$I \frac{4_1}{a} m d$](https://it.iucr.org/Ac/ch2o3v0001/sgtable2o3o141/).

[image: $I \frac{4_1}{a} m d]

And here's all 230 space groups' symbols.

[image: 230 space groups' symbols]

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question to include a screenshot of what you want it to look like? When clicking on your iucr.org URL, I'm asked to sign in, so I can't see what the webpage looks like.

Comment: Sorry @gz839918, I've updated the question.

Comment: The article is behind a paywall. In the image you posted I see no special formatting and `$I4_1/\mathit{amd}$` should do.